# Why React doesn't render my result after setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having the below jsx code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RemoteAssets from '../modules/RemoteAssets';



class RemoteOptions extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            RemoteOptions: []
        }
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        const { api, locale } = this.props;
        RemoteAssets.loadRemoteOptions({ api, locale }).then((RemoteOptions) => {
            console.log( 'RemoteOptions', RemoteOptions);
            this.setState((state, props) => ({
                RemoteOptions
            }), () => {
                this.render()
            });
        })

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-4">
                    <label >Opt: </label>
                </div>
                <div className=" col-8">
                    {JSON.stringify(this.state.RemoteOptions)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default RemoteOptions;
```

This is what happens to me:

componentDidMount logs correctly the payload expected.

```
 console.log( 'RemoteOptions', RemoteOptions);
```

So I believe that It will also set State as expected:

```
            this.setState((state, props) => ({
                RemoteOptions
            }), () => {
                this.render()
            });
```

I also added above a this.render() stmt to be sure the component will be re-rendered after updating the state.

But :

```
   {JSON.stringify(this.state.RemoteOptions)}
```

Will always return "[]" as the init state before componentDidMount happens and update the state.

How should I arrange this component to have my render update the with the payòoad loaded async?

Comment: have you got any error messages in your console?

Comment: no errors in my console

Comment: Just to be sure, did you try: `this.setState({ RemoteOptions: RemoteOptions })` ?

Comment: What does the data coming back from the API call actually spit out, i.e., what does the variable RemoteOptions look like? I think @LiJonas 's answer might be right however, the way you're calling setState ((state, prop) => { }) is for updating, not for setting.

Answer (score 4):

## Name conflict

Your state name and class name are in conflict.

```
class RemoteOptions extends Component { // class name
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            RemoteOptions: []           // state name
        }
    }
    ...
```

Call your state something different.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply using setState the way documentation suggests?

```
this.setState({ RemoteOptions });
```

Render method will be automatically called right after the state is set.

Comment: @koalaok do you get this log? `this.setState({ RemoteOptions }, () => console.log('state has been set'));`

Comment: yes I do get It. And I get also a this.setState({ RemoteOptions }, () => console.log('state has been set', RemoteOptions)); with the expected result of RemoteOptions.

Comment: @koalaok do you get desired result from `this.setState({ RemoteOptions }, () => console.log(this.state.RemoteOptions));` as well?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the skeleton of the problem, and everything works as expected.

```js
const loadRemoteOptions = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('myRemoteOptions'), 1000)
})


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    remoteOptions: null
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    loadRemoteOptions().then(remoteOptions => this.setState({ remoteOptions }))
  }
  
  render(){
    return this.state.remoteOptions || 'Loading...';
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```